# In PHP, how do I use conditionals while reading text file?

Tags: php, file, if-statement

I have a text file full of names, followed by a tab, then a number. 
Example:
name    1
othername    2
thirdname    1

I want to make php read that file, turn each line into an array, test if the number on that line is "1! and if it is, echo out the name. 
How would I go about doing that?

```
    $read = fopen($pp, "r");
    while(!feof($read) && $line= fgets($read)) {
        if (explode("\t", $line)[1] === "1") {
            echo explode("\t", $line)[0] . ", ";
        }
    } fclose($read);
```

Comment: I would get the line inside the while loop, then explode and test. Assign the explode array to a variable so you don't have to perform a second explode and you can just `echo $variable[0]`

Comment: I'd go along the lines, but use regex for splitting the line. The only downside in both solutions - initial data format must be fixed, although regex allows some leeway in separators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little modification to your code should work - get the line inside the while loop, then explode and test. Assign the explode array to a variable so you don't have to perform a second explode and you can just `echo $variable[0]`

```
$read = fopen($pp, "r");
while(!feof($read)) {
    $line = fgets($read);
    $arr = explode("\t", $line);
    if ($arr[1] === "1") {
        echo $arr[0] . ", ";
    }
} 
fclose($read);
```